# Installing .NET Framework 3.5 requires .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: windows, windows-10, .net-framework

I have a Windows 10 machine that doesn't have Internet access. So I downloaded the .NET 3.5 Framework from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=25150

I copied the installer to the Windows 10 machine, and attempted to install. I get the following dialog, which appears to be telling me I need .NET Framework 3.5 to install .NET Framework 3.5:

[image]

What else do I need to install this? The installer I have is 330MB, so I assume it's the full package and not the web installer.

Comment: Could it be that the offline package you carried over doesn't include .NET 2.0 and 3.0 and the installation is looking for either of those 2?

Comment: @JJT I'm downloading 2.0 and 3.0. Will update once they've downloaded.

Comment: Tried to install 3.0 ... same problem.

Comment: Aye. Windows just doesn't jive offline as it used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need netframe work 3.5 to install old software. old software use netframe 3.5.
Next you have to install visual studio enterprise 2015 for netframe work 4.6. this software include all the necessary distribution(include silverlight) that windows and apps needed

here is the link:
http://getintopc.com/softwares/development/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-iso-free-download/

after this download, you may not need windows update anymore to update for windows 10

Answer (score 0):

What you do isn't a typical way of installing .NET 3.5 on Windows.

Typical way is without using the installer:

1. go to **Programs and Features** > **Turn Windows features on or off**
2. check item **.NET Framework 3.5**

This will add .NET 3.5. I'm using this all the time when I find that machine has .NET missing.

Comment: The problem with this is it requires Internet. The machine I am using doesn't have Internet access.

Comment: I see. I admit I did not face this problem so far. Then try going with installer of older .NET first.